# Office365 how to recover entire dumpster

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I need to recover an entire deleteditem aka dumpster folder.

Using `Get-MailboxStatistics User@Domain.com | Select *Deleted*` I am able to see 2.2+GB of data = 9,700+ emails.

How can I recover all of these?

I have seen `Search-Mailbox "Discovery Search Mailbox" -SearchQuery <search query> -TargetMailbox <user> -TargetFolder inbox` which I assume would work, but only for single searches and items. I need a batch solution. Any Office 365 PowerShell gurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to piece together a solution. The following command recovered all contents:

```
Search-Mailbox "user@domain.com" -TargetMailbox tmprecoveryemailacct@domain.com -TargetFolder inbox
```

I needed to use `Search-Mailbox` without `-SearchQuery`. Apparently no wildcard options worked, but omitting it worked as a wildcard. Also, another caveat, you need to recover to a separate mailbox (much like HDD recovery, why I don't know). Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: After running this (took about 4 hours) I realize this is not fine tuned enough. Expect an edit to this solution. As I stated in the question the `Get-MailboxStatistics` command resulted in 2.2GB of data in 9,700 emails...This solution resulted in the recovery of too much: ~7.9GB of data in ~35,000 emails. I need to somehow figure out how to pipe it through a `findstr` or something similar. Still open for any/all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You probably already have the answer, but for posterity, you may specify `-SearchDumpsterOnly` so it  only returns deleted items:

```
Search-Mailbox -SearchDumpsterOnly "user@domain.com" -TargetMailbox tmprecoveryemailacct@domain.com -TargetFolder inbox
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately search-mailbox cmdlet is no longer available. not sure why they removed it. There is no option to recover ONLY recoverable items..